# How to store a buffer in a variable so that the value of the variable isn't influenced by the fate of the buffer?

Tags: buffers, variables

Say I'm in a buffer named `init.el` and I run

```lisp
(setq mybuffer (current-buffer))
```

If I evaluate `mybuffer` I get `#<buffer init.el>`. Now I kill this buffer and evaluate `mybuffer` again. Emacs returns `#<killed buffer>`. I'd like it to return `#<buffer init.el>` again, instead.

The reason for this is that I use a variable to store a buffer I want to switch back to, and I'd like to be able to switch to it even after killing and reopening it.

I'd like to avoid storing with `buffer-name` and retrieving with `get-buffer` so as to deal only with buffer objects.

Comment: The question isn't too clear. This has nothing to do with variables, IIUC. Once you've killed a buffer it's a killed buffer. Any pointer/reference to it (such as a variable) just gives you it.

Comment: Have you tried virtual buffers?  Both helm and ivy support that (and good old ido, but use ivy instead).  Note this is an interactive feature, not a lisp thing -- I'm just guessing at what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @CroadLangshan Hey what's wrong with Ido? :-) I already use them and in effect they may be useful for my thing. I'll take it easy though, because I don't know how to handle them from the Lisp side yet. What my thing does is put two buffers in a vector of two elements and use a key binding to switch back and forth between them. Even if I take a detour to other buffers, the key switches back to one of them two and then to the other. After I close one of the two however, it returns `invalid buffer` and it does so even if I reopen that buffer. That's what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge to solve that you'd have to use file names (or some other specification of how to recreate buffers) for the reason Drew cited.  You might also like to consider persp-mode.el (again not the same thing, but similar purpose).  Nothing wrong with ido if you're using it happily of course, ivy just has had a lot of development effort in recent years

Comment: Maybe this is interesting to you https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/l4v1ux/one_of_the_most_useful_small_lisp_functions_in_my/